# How to run a Visual Studio on Parallels Desktop with Elevated privilages via dock icon

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop, windows, administrator

I have a OS X Mavericks with Parallels Desktop 9 hosting Windows 8.1 on it. Windows has Visual Studio 2013 installed.

I am working in Coherence mode. If I run Visual Studio from Start menu or some other way, it appears in OS X dock. I can choose to Keep it in dock.

But I need VS to start with Elevated (admin) privileges. The devenv.exe, which is a Visual Studio executable, doesn't have a Compatibility tab where I could check the Always run in Admin mode, which would solve my problem.

How can I have Visual Studio in dock and have it being executed with Admin right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to launch devenv through runas.exe, there you can specify the user who you want. 
So you should make a shortcut with the following command:

```
runas.exe /user:admin "c:\PATHTODEVENV\devenv.exe
```

As I know it will ask your password, but then you can try the /savecred switch.

More info: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249705/how-to-run-an-app-as-run-as-administrator-from-command-prompt, and 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx
Good Luck!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I dont understand what I'm supposed to do with this on a mac.